# What is the Remainder in the Eclipse Memory Analyser main pie chart?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I just started learning about memory management for Android. After doing a memory dump on the application I am working on and analyzing it with Eclipse Memory Analyzer, I found out that 37MB (out of the 50M retained memory) was taken by a "Remainder". This 50M figure matches my logcat retained memory, so I guess this Remainder does occupy some memory:

```
GC_CONCURRENT freed 12839K, 21% free 50038K/62908K, paused 7ms+15ms, total 144ms
```

Does somebody know what this Remainder is usually made of? Can this be a sign that I have some memory leak?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the remainder is that the remained part, which are not as dominant as the previous ones.

For instances:

1) Bitmap occupies 10M

2) Resource occupies 5M

3) RelativeLayout occupies 100K

4) LinearLayout occupies 20K
...

on the map, only 1) 2) show up, and 3), 4) ... are included in the remainder.